# Best PHP class to parse mail from raw body?

Tags: php, mime

As sources, i have variables composed by the raw email, with headers and body:

```
From: Guy <mail>
Subject: Stuff
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-15; format=flowed
X-etc: etc etc etc

This is the raw body.
(body in some cases also contains quoted printable encoding, attachments, base64, etc etc)
```

I repeat it: i have this as text in variables, if not i would use imap_fetchbody (that requires a remote mailbox to work, can't get raw inputs)

I also found this library that seems to be quite complete: http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_mimeDecode

What is the best class i can use?

Comment: You probably already found it.

Answer (score 0):

[mailparse](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mailparse.php) if you get it installed for php is very efficient because it does not keep in memory messages.